# Postgres CTE exponentially saving time?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I would love some clear explanation on the below, I would have thought PG would have optimized the first query to be just as fast as the second query, which uses a CTE, since it's basically using a simple index to filter and join on 2 columns. Everything in the joins and filtering, except "l"."type", has an index. This would be on PG 10.

The below takes 20 minutes+.

```
    SELECT
      transactions.id::text AS id,
      transactions.amount,
      transactions.currency::text AS currency,
      transactions.external_id::text AS external_id,
      transactions.check_sender_balance,
      transactions.created,
      transactions.type::text AS type,
      transactions.sequence,
      transactions.legacy_id::text AS legacy_id,
      transactions.reference_transaction::text AS reference_transaction,
      a.user_id as user_id
   FROM transactions
   JOIN lines l ON transactions.id = l.transaction
   JOIN accounts a ON l.account = a.id
   WHERE l.type='DEBIT'
   AND "sequence" > 357550718
   AND user_id IN ('5bf4ceb45d27fd2985a000000')
```

But the following, which I suppose explicitly optimizes accounts via CTE, finishes in ~2-4minutes. I would have thought PG would have optimized to match this type of performance?

```
    WITH "accts" AS (
      SELECT "id", "user_id"
      FROM "accounts" WHERE "user_id" IN ('5bf4ceb45d27fd2985a000000')
    )
    SELECT "transactions"."id"::TEXT                    AS "id",
         "transactions"."amount",
         "transactions"."currency"::TEXT              AS "currency",
         "transactions"."external_id"::TEXT           AS "external_id",
         "transactions"."check_sender_balance",
         "transactions"."created",
         "transactions"."type"::TEXT                  AS "type",
         "transactions"."sequence",
         "transactions"."legacy_id"::TEXT             AS "legacy_id",
         "transactions"."reference_transaction"::TEXT AS "reference_transaction",
         a."user_id"                   AS "user_id"
    FROM "transactions"
    JOIN "lines" "l" ON "transactions"."id" = "l"."transaction"
    JOIN "accts" "a" ON "a"."id" = "l"."account"
    WHERE "l"."type" = 'DEBIT'
    AND "sequence" > 357550718
```

Comment: This was changed in Postgres 12. Prior to that, the CTE and the final SELECT where optimized separately which sometimes was a good thing and sometimes it was not (e.g. in your case)

Answer (score 1):

You have a second predicate in your second query vs your first. In your second in the CTE you are limiting it to only a specific user_id. Nowhere in your first query do you have that filter. If there is an index on the user_id field then it is probably helping your performance. You can run an explain plan on both queries separately by adding EXPLAIN to the beginning of them and see how the plan differs. This will help you figure out why there is a difference.

Comment: I don't understand, both queries are limiting by `user_id`, right? Each has 3 basic filters, the `l.type = "debit"`, `sequence > some number`, and in the first query,`"AND user_id IN ('5bf4ceb45d27fd2985a000000')`

Comment: user_id is constrained in both queries.  But the EXPLAIN advice is still good.